# least square approximation: how this matrix calculation equation is deducted?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I am reading a book "kernel methods for pattern analysis". For the least square approximation, it is to minimise the sum of the square of the discrepancies:

$$e=y-Xw$$
Therefore it is to minimize 
$$ L(w,S)=(y-Xw)'(y-Xw)$$
Leading to 
$$ w=(X'X)^{-1} X'y $$

I understand until here.
 But how does it leads to this as following? **What is $\alpha$ here exactly? Is it constant?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is directly in that formula of the remark:
$$
\mathbf{w}=(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-2}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{\alpha},
$$
where
$$
\boldsymbol{\alpha}=\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-2}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{y}=(\mathbf{X}^{\dagger})'\mathbf{X}^{\dagger}\mathbf{y}
$$
and $\mathbf{X}^{\dagger}=(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'$ is the pseudo inverse of $\mathbf{X}$.
So if the rows of $\mathbf{X}$ are $\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_{\ell}$, that is, $\mathbf{X}'=[\mathbf{x}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{x}_{\ell}]$, and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{\ell}]'$, then
$$
\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{X}'\boldsymbol{\alpha}=\sum_{i=1}^{\ell}\alpha_i\mathbf{x}_i.
$$

Comment: so the formula for $\alpha$ can not be further expanded?

Comment: @Tyler expanded in terms of what?